# Rotate two parrarel lines some radius - maintain the distance between

Tags: c#, wpf

is it possible to rotate two parrarel lines with distance between them by some radius?

To better imagine, let say that these two lines are the only two lines that are visible from a rectangle at specific distance from the circle center, and these two lines are on the sides of the rectangle (bottom is side to the center, top is the side out of the circle), so the rotation is done by moving the rectangle over the edge of the circle, perserving the distance from the circle center.

If there would be lines going throught the centre of the circle, the math is quite simple. But these two lines are going near the circle center, but there is a little distance from the center to the left and right.

My approach was to try calculate the line that is in the middle of these two lines and therefore is going throught the circle center.But than I stuck with calculation, how should these two lines move according this calculated "helping" line.

[Edited: Added image]

[image: Top is origin position, right is desired (or any other angle)]

Comment: If the problem is easier to solve if one line crosses the center, transform your coordinates so that it *does* cross the center. After the rotation, transform it back to the original

Comment: I've added an image of the problem. I can move them after rotation to the sides - recalculated them from the centre one - if the angle is 0,90,180,270 degrees, but in other angles it's quite problem, for example 60 degrees. Then it not just move them in x-axis or y-axis, but both and the movement step has to be calculated on some algorithm which currently I can't find out.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told how you actually draw you shapes, but something like the XAML below should do what you want. The two Lines are drawn in a common Canvas parent which is rotated by a RotateTransform that has its center at the center of the circle.

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="200,200" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Canvas>
        <Line X1="190" Y1="50" X2="190" Y2="150" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Line X1="210" Y1="50" X2="210" Y2="150" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="200" CenterY="200"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                            To="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Canvas.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I'm in position, where XAML is not an option, because lines are created dynamically via code behind and these objects will be rotated separatelly.

Comment: Everything in the above XAML can also be done in code behind. Please be more specific the next time you ask a question.